# Show that $x \ln(ex) - \sqrt{x}\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 1$

Tags: logarithms

How do I continue to prove this?

Show that
$$
x \ln(ex) - \sqrt{x}\geq 0 
$$
for all 
$$
x \geq1
$$

My try:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\\
\ln(e^x) + \ln(x^x) &\geq&  \sqrt{x} 
\\
\\
\ln(e^x) &\geq&  \sqrt{x} - \ln(x^x)
\\ \\
e^x &\geq & e^\sqrt{x} e^{-\ln(x^x)}
\\ \\
e^x&\geq& e^\sqrt{x} (1/x^x)
\\ \\
e^x - \frac{e^\sqrt{x}}{x^x}&\geq& 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$

I "see" that this is bigger than 0, but I think that there are more calculations to do.

Comment: Let $x$ be positive but less than $1/e$. Then our expression is clearly negative. So you will have to change the condition $x\ge 0$ to something else.

Comment: @AndréNicolas He actually wants $x\geq 1$.

Comment: You have an error: $e^{-\ln x^x}\ne -x^x$; but rather $e^{-\ln x^x}= e^{\ln (1/x^x)}=1/x^x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thanks.

Comment: Okay, but now I think it's obivous that this is bigger than 0?

Comment: You still need to correct the last two lines in your argument.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yep, fixed that now.

Comment: Correction, meant x>=1!

Comment: @JulianAssange:I already mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Then you might note $\ln(ex)\ge\ln(e)=1$; so, $x\ln(ex)-\sqrt x\ge x-\sqrt x=\sqrt x(\sqrt x-1)\ge 0$. Or, better, look at Peter's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function

$$f\left( x \right) = x\log \left( {ex} \right) - \sqrt x  = x\log x + x - \sqrt x $$

$\log x$ is positive for $x>1$ and negative for $0<x<1$.

And $x>\sqrt x$ for $x>1$, and $x<\sqrt x$ for $0<x<1$. Thus

$$\begin{cases} f(x)>0 \text{ for } x>1\\ f(x)<0  \text{ for } 0<x<1\\f(x)=0 \text{ for }x=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, but I meant x>=0.

Comment: @JulianAssange I'm showing you the inequality is not true for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant x >= 1. :)

Comment: @JulianAssange I showed you that is true, too. Did you read the answer carefully?

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted you to know. :=)

Answer (score 3):

Substitute 1/e for x. Of course 1/e is greater than zero. But ln(e*1/e) equals zero, so your Left Hand Side is negative, equals to -1/sqrt{e}. Therefore, the inequality you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: You should probably edit this to say that it was for the original version of the problem, which claimed the inequality for all $x\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x\ln(ex)-\sqrt x$.  Note that $f'(x)=\ln(ex)+1 -\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}>0 \;(*)$  for $x\geq1$, and so $f$ is increasing from $x=1$.  But $f(1)=0$, and so $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 1$.

$(*)$ This can be seen since $\ln(ex)+1$ is increasing, and $\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt x}$ is decreasing, so $f'(x)$ must be increasing.  Since $f'(1)>0$, we thus must have this inequality for all $x\geq1$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is true for $x \geq 1$. Put $f(x)=x\ln({\rm e}x)-\sqrt{x}$ and use the derivative test to prove that.

Comment: How does one prove that? I know that the function is acting like an exponential function, but is it enough to derivate and see that the interval from x >= 1 is growing?

Comment: @JulianAssange: Just look at any calculus book under applications of derivative (finding maximum and minimum of functions). I'll try to post it later.

Comment: @JulianAssange See my answer...